# sf v2 CLI does not work with VSCode Salesforce Extensions

Tags: vs-code, sf-cli, sf-v2-cli

I have upgraded to `sf (v2)` from `sfdx (v7)`

As per documentation:

- [Move from sfdx (v7) to sf (v2)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_move_to_sf_v2.htm)

Which involved uninstalling `sfdx (v7)`

But now when using `VSCode` the commands it generates no longer work.

For example

> Command Palette: SFDX Authorize an Org

Will generate a command like:

> sfdx org:login:web --alias my-org --instance-url https://x.my.salesforce.com --set-default

How do I configure `VSCode` to use `sf v2`?

Comment: sf still have a back support for sfdx commands. Where is it failing? What is the error message?
VSCode salesforce plugin, is not internally upgraded to use `sf` commands, this cannot be configured from settings. VScode salesforce plugin team needs to upgrade their extension code to use `sf` commands.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be configured from settings. I also faced this same issue. After going through multiple posts the following steps worked for me. I am on Windows 11.

1. Remove/Uninstall all Salesforce CLIs. My earlier installtions were
   through installers, so I uninstalled them from add/remove program.
   Remove all the traces like removing the Path entry in System
   Settings. Check the status by running `sfdx` and `sf` commands.
2. Then follow the installtion with `npm` as described in this link
   [Move from sfdx (v7) to sf (v2)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_move_to_sf_v2.htm). The main commands are `1) npm uninstall sfdx-cli --global` `2) npm install @salesforce/cli --global`. Now both `sf` and `sfdx` commands will work as `sfdx` is now aliased to `sf`. You can verify this by running `sf version` and `sfdx version`. Both will return same result.

Now open your VSCode and you can see the generated sfdx commands will work as earlier.

Comment: `sfdx version` returns `C:\Users\Robs\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\bin\..\7.209.6-8ba3197\bin\sfdx.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I had to uninstall using command line, and delete files from `C:\Users\Robs\AppData\Local` and from `C:\Program Files`